# How Does WCF Service handles a big number of request?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

So If I have a WCF service running how can I know how many requests can be handled by the service. Also is there any built-in queuing mechanism?

Comment: You can know by performing a performance test in your environment, or one similar to it. There is no other way to know.

Comment: I thought that we can configure the queue/thread count in some configurations file. I tried searching but didnt find anything.

Comment: Even if you could configure that, you will never know _how_ to configure it without performing tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your hardware. To monitor WCF you can use system counters [WCF Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098).